# Update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header

Tags: bash, autorun

So I'm trying to install ka-lite onto my raspberry pi and when I install I am getting the following error. I'll manually run the runatboot.sh file and get the same exact error. I'm not sure what to do or how to fix this.

I'm getting this error

```
     sudo ./runatboot.sh
    update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
    insserv: warning: script 'start.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
    insserv: There is a loop between service monit and start.sh if stopped
    insserv:  loop involving service start.sh at depth 2
    insserv:  loop involving service monit at depth 1
    insserv: Stopping start.sh depends on monit and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
    insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
    update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
```

This is my start.sh file

```
    cat start.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    ### BEGIN INIT INFO
    # Provides:          kalite
    ### END INIT INFO

    if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]; then
        echo "Error: KA-Lite must be started by a regular user, not by root"
        exit 1
    fi

    SCRIPT_DIR=`dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`
    if [ -e "$SCRIPT_DIR/python.sh" ]; then
        KALITE_DIR=$SCRIPT_DIR/../kalite
    else
        KALITE_DIR=$SCRIPT_DIR/kalite
        SCRIPT_DIR=$SCRIPT_DIR/scripts
    fi

    # move any previously downloaded content from the old location to the new
    mv "$KALITE_DIR/static/videos/*" "$KALITE_DIR/../content" > /dev/null 2> /dev/null

    echo
    source "$SCRIPT_DIR/serverstart.sh"

    echo
    source "$SCRIPT_DIR/cronstart.sh"
```

this is the runatboot.sh file

```
    cat runatboot.sh
    #!/bin/bash

    SCRIPT_DIR=`dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`
    KALITE_DIR=$SCRIPT_DIR/../kalite
    pyexec=`"$SCRIPT_DIR/python.sh"`

    UNAME=`uname`
    if [ "$UNAME" == "Darwin" ]; then
        F=/$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/org.learningequality.kalite.plist
        "$pyexec" "$KALITE_DIR/manage.py" initdconfig > "$F"
        chmod 644 "$F"
    elif [ "$UNAME" == "Linux" ]; then
        "$pyexec" "$KALITE_DIR/manage.py" initdconfig > /etc/init.d/kalite
        chmod 755 /etc/init.d/kalite
        update-rc.d kalite defaults
    fi
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

insserv: warning: script 'start.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
To remove above error description should be like :

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:  <user entry>
# Required-Start: <user entry: please add even if empty.>
# Required-Stop: <user entry: please add even if empty.>
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:  0 1 6
# Short-Description: 
### END INIT INFO
```

Comment: One other notes : Provides: It Must be the name of the script